# Listings for OCaml and quotes

Tags: listings

The listings syntax highlighting for OCaml breaks whenever the OCaml literal character `'"'` appears in the source.

It's not possible to let the language definition treat single quotes as a delimiter for string literals because single quotes are also used for type variables (e.g. `'a list`)

The following document shows the problem. On the last line of the output the `let` keyword should be in bold. This doesn't happen because listings thinks it is inside a string literal. If we treat single quotes as string literal delimiters then first line breaks the rendering of the subsequent lines.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
 language=caml,
 columns=[c]fixed,
 basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
 keywordstyle=\bfseries,
 upquote=true,
 commentstyle=,
 breaklines=true,
 showstringspaces=false}
\begin{document}
 \begin{lstlisting}
 type 'a t = ..
 let double_quote = '"'
 let broken_highlight = ()
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to configure the listings package for OCaml so that this problem doesn't happen ?

Comment: Also I tried to add `morekeywords={'"'}` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case you can use the `literate` option which doesn't break with double-quoted strings or other highlighting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
 language=caml,
 columns=[c]fixed,
% basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
 keywordstyle=\bfseries,
 upquote=true,
 commentstyle=,
 breaklines=true,
 showstringspaces=false,
 stringstyle=\color{blue},
 literate={'"'}{\textquotesingle "\textquotesingle}3
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{lstlisting}
 type 'a t = ..
 let double_quote = "foo"
 let double_quote = '"'
 let double_quote = 'a'
 let double_quote = "'"
 let broken_highlight = ()
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks works as advertised. More specificially the interested OCaml typsetter may want to add: 

`literate={'"'}{\textquotesingle "\textquotesingle}3
          {'\\"'}{\textquotesingle\textbackslash "\textquotesingle}4`

Answer (score 3):

You could consider switching to `minted`, which handles this input correctly. There is a black and white style available with the option `style=bw`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{ocaml}
type 'a t = { name : string; mutable info : 'a};;
let p = { name = "John"; info = 23 };;
let double_quote = '"'
let broken_highlight = ()
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[style=bw]{ocaml}
type 'a t = { name : string; mutable info : 'a};;
let p = { name = "John"; info = 23 };;
let double_quote = '"'
let broken_highlight = ()
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of this package, my only gripe is that it relies on external software. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The package `piton` handles this input without problem. The package `piton` requires LuaLaTeX but does not use any exterior software.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{piton,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{Piton}[language=ocaml]
type 'a t = { name : string; mutable info : 'a};;
let p = { name = "John"; info = 23 };;
let double_quote = '"'
let broken_highlight = ()
\end{Piton}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]